# R Venn Diagram Questions

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I had a couple of questions regarding Venn Diagrams in R:

1. Is there a way to add "K" or "M" after each quantity for Venn Diagrams? Because the inputs have to be
   numbers I'm not sure how to add that onto the label so it shows up in the Venn Diagram image itself.
2. For whole numbers, like 2, it shows up as "2" even though I have the decimal points as 1. How do I adjust so that integers also have a ".0" at the end?
3. I have quantities that are overlapping in small circles so that it can't be read. Is there an option to manually move them so they don't overlap over each other?

Edit:
I'm using the Eulerr package

Sample code:

```
plot(euler(c( "LUTS"=98, "Symptoms of UTI"=46, "Positive urine culture"=39, "Symptoms of UTI&LUTS"=33, "LUTS&Positive urine culture"=24, "Symptoms of UTI&Positive urine culture"=22, "Symptoms of UTI&LUTS&Positive urine culture"=18), input = "union", shape = "ellipse"), key = TRUE, counts = TRUE, quantities = list(type = c("counts", "percent"), font=3, round=2, cex=0.8), fills =list(fill=c(viridis::plasma(n = 3))), alpha = 0.3, c("#1957FF", "#FF750C", "#FF220C"), alpha = 0.3, edges=list(lty = 1), factor_names = TRUE, labels=list(font=2, cex=1), legend = FALSE)
```

Comment: What package are you using? Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) with example code and data?

Comment: @Alexlok Thanks for replying. I am using the Eulerr package and I just added example code but I'm finding that it's a similar issue with the VennDiagram package as well